# How can I store the result of an SQL COUNT statement in a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the number of rows in my MySQL table and store that number in a php variable. This is the code I'm using:

```
$size = @mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM News");
```

$size ends up being "Resource ID #7." How do I put the number of rows directly into $size?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why is this a wiki?

Comment: I asked this back before I knew what a community wiki was.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

mysql_query returns a query resource id. In order to get values from it you need to use mysql_fetch_assoc on the resource id to fetch a row into an array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM News");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$size = $row['COUNT(*)'];
```

Comment: I haven't used php in a while, but won't it not release the $result if you don't loop through until mysql_fetch_assoc returns a null?  Shouldn't it usually be used with a while loop, or is there another way to tell mysql that you don't want any more rows from $result?

Comment: Nevermind, found this on the doc page:  "// Note: If you're expecting just one row, no need to use a loop".

Comment: You could do mysql_free_result( $result ), but you could argue that was unnecessary - the result buffer is only going to contain one row, in any case, and all the resources will be freed when the script exits.

Comment: mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM News"); would be a lot cleaner also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call [mysql_fetch_row](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) or one of its [sister functions](http://us.php.net/mysql).

```
<?php
// untested
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM News");
// error handling
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$count = $row[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$size = @mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM News");
$query = mysql_fetch_array($size);
echo $query['total'];
```

Answer (score -1):

On a related note you can use the [mysql_num_rows()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function to obtain the number of rows from a given query. This is handy if you need to grab the data but also know the number of rows.

```
<?php
  $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
  $count = @mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
```